# Object returned from fetch request has incorrect data

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, core-data

I am attempting to get an object from a fetch request, and I am checking a property of that object.

Depending on what type the property is will cause me to display a notification or not.  After making a successful connection, I set the property type of my object to 'updated' from 'inserted.'  Then, when I refresh my view, I pull all objects from coredata and check their properties for the 'updated' type.  The problem I am having is that the objects returned in my fetch request that I just attempted to change to 'updated' still display the old 'inserted' value from the fetch request, but don't immediately after the submission.  Its like they are reverting.  (and I AM saving the context)

What is even more confusing is I have gotten a program to look at the actual tables in the database file stored on the device, and it actually shows the correct value of updated in the table.  But the fetch request still comes back with the object having incorrect data.  And no amount of refreshing fixes the issue.

How can a fetch request be giving me objects with old/incorrect data when the coredata file shows the tables with correct values?

```
 // code for the fetch request

// return an array of all assets for a specific customer
NSFetchRequest *fetchReq = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Asset"];
fetchReq.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"customerID = %@" argumentArray:[NSArray arrayWithObject:customerID]];
NSArray *results = [[CoreDataManager sharedManager] executeFetchRequest:fetchReq];

return results;

//executeFetchRequest method
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContextForCurrentThread];
NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
return results;
```

Comment: Post the code of how your creating the fetch request. If your fetching on the same context that your saving on it, you can try resetting the context before performing the fetch request again.

Comment: added the fetch request

Comment: How is the "property type" stored? Name/type of the attribute?

Comment: @MartinR Its an NSNumber

Comment: What is the name of the attribute? (I am asking because some property names can cause strange effects, e.g. "deleted"  or "updated".)

Comment: updateType is the name of the property.  The value being stored is an ENUM designated 'inserted' or 'updated' etc.  Then set to an NSNumber when its stored

Comment: [self managedObjectContextForCurrentThread] - I think this can cause a problem, as different contexts can have different version of NSManagedObjects. You can call [fetchReq setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:YES] and it will return the most up-to-date version of your objects.

Comment: @Arcanfel I believe this was the issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Arcanfel's suggestion (in comments to the original question) certainly helped me find the solution to my own problem, but it was hidden in the 'Show more comments' section.

It would have been helpful to see that as an answer, not a comment, so I've taken his comment and expanded it a little.

Original comment:

> [self managedObjectContextForCurrentThread] - I think this can cause a
>   problem, as different contexts can have different version of
>   NSManagedObjects. You can call [fetchReq
>   setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:YES] and it will return the most
>   up-to-date version of your objects

Whilst using the setShouldRefreshRefetchedObjects:YES didn't resolve my problem of subsequent fetch requests not bringing back the right data, it did make me look at my context management.

In one method I was setting the context, and then reading data.  In another method I was setting another context, reading data, altering it and then saving that context... a different context to what my first method had.

In short, be careful that you're referring to the same context or anything you update in context1 won't be in synch with what you retrieve from context2.